# Cloning a path when clicking and dragging it using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have a hidden path.
I would like to clone it when I click somewhere in a div, and be able to drag it when I click and hold on it.

The problem is, once I'm done dragging around the path, **releasing the mouse button results in another path being created**.

I'm using both Raphael.js and JQuery, and here's the code I use:

```
var c = Raphael("holder", 640, 480);
var p = c.path("M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z").hide().attr("fill", "#c0c0c0");
function getCenter (bbox) {
    return [Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0), Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0)];
};

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#holder').click(function (e) {
        var posX = $(this).position().left, posY = $(this).position().top;
        var [x,y] = getCenter(p.getBBox());
        p.clone()
            .transform("T"+[(e.pageX-posX-x),(e.pageY-posY-y)])
            .drag(
        function (dx, dy) {     
            this.transform("t"+(e.pageX-posX-x+dx)+","+(e.pageY-posY-y+dy));
        },
        function () {},
        function () {});
    });
});
```

Here's a JSfiddle that shows the weird behaviour.
http://jsfiddle.net/2gggp/3/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#holder').click(function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).is("path")) 
     return false;
   ...
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, a new path is cloned when you *release* the mouse button. Now that I see the issue, it's not as weird as I thought it was.